# Functions ( derivatives and stationary points )

Tags: calculus, functions

Going through past exam papers and have came across a question that i'm quite frankly clueless about.

> Given the function $$f(x) = \ln(x^2-2x+2)$$
>   a) Compute the derivative $f'(x)$
>
> b) Find and classify the stationary point of $f(x)$

I've literally no idea how to even attempt this question..thanks in advance for anyone that could show me in a step by step manor of how to compute this

Comment: For computing the derivative, have you tried applying the chain rule?

Answer (score 2):

Part (a) is just an application of the chain rule: this function is of the form $f(x) = g(h(x))$ where $g(u) = \ln(u)$ and $h(x) = x^2 - 2x + 2$. Then the chain rule informs us:

$$
f'(x) = g'(h(x)) h'(x) = \frac{1}{h(x)} (2x - 2) = \frac{2x-2}{x^2 - 2x + 2}.
$$

For part (b), you need to find the values of $x$ so that $f'(x) = 0$, i.e. for what $x$ is
$$
\frac{2x-2}{x^2 - 2x + 2} = 0?
$$

I'll leave this part to you, along with the reminder that a fraction is zero when the numerator is zero and the denominator is not. (so just look for values of $x$ that make the numerator zero, and check that the denominator is not zero there)

Comment: Thanks..but i have no idea where you're getting all this from :P  for part A, i'm clueless how you worked all that out =/ i really needed help with the steps because you've only really given me the answer; i'm trying to revise :P

Comment: What is the context in which you are trying to understand this problem? Are you in a calculus course? If so, have you learned the differentiation rules for polynomials and $\ln(x)$? Have you learned the chain rule?

Comment: I'm on Computer Science, but the Maths is being taught at a higher level than i'm at ( i got in with a fairly low maths grade compared to majority ). I've never heard of the chain rule, since we've been taught it. They seem to bring graphs into functions when we done it

Comment: Then I suggest you look for a supplemental calculus resource and read through the sections on the material I mentioned above. No offense, but the solution to the above problem is really "use basic techniques from calculus" and if you haven't been taught those techniques, you're going to have to learn them on your own (and then do a bunch of practice problems). You might also find it useful to work with classmates who have a better understanding than you, and see what explanations they can offer.

Comment: hey, looking at examples atm. What des the ln mean? can't see these youtube guys including ln in their functions

Comment: $\ln$ is 'natural log'. If you know about 'regular' logarithms, $\ln(x) = \log_e(x)$. If not, try maybe watching some Khan academy videos, etc. I'm guessing the examples you're watching just don't happen to include a logarithm.

Comment: Here are some KA videos you might watch. 

logarithms: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/logarithms-tutorial/logarithm_basics/v/logarithms

derivatives of polynomials: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/differential-calculus/power_rule_tutorial/v/power-rule

derivative of $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/differential-calculus/der_common_functions/v/proofs-of-derivatives-of-ln-x--and-e-x

chain rule: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/differential-calculus/chain_rule/v/the-chain-rule